# Maximum record length in a text file using Windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd

How to find the maximum record length in a text file using Windows command. i.e, it should output the maximum length of the line found in that file.

Comment: basically trying to figure out "wc -L " in command line

Comment: Why no download `wc`? e.g. http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ or http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Comment: is there no way that i can do it in command line ? :(

Comment: Yes, with the `wc` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a batch implementation of the `wc -L` (give input file as argument to batch)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"

    for %%f in ("%~1") do (
        cmd /c "(type "%%~ff"&echo(&echo()" | findstr /o /r /c:"^" > "%tempFile%"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set /a "max=0", "last=0"
        for /f "usebackq delims=:" %%a in ("%tempFile%") do (
            set /a "length=%%a-last-2"
            set "last=%%a"
            if !length! gtr !max! set "max=!length!"
        )
        echo !max! "%%~ff"
        endlocal
        del /q "%tempFile%" 2> nul 
    )
```

What is does is generate a temporary file with all the lines prefixed with its offset inside the file using `findstr`. The rest is substract the offset of the current line from the offset of the previous one to calculate its length. Two aditional lines are added to the temporary file used (`for /f` loads files much faster than it retrieve command output) to ensure the last line in the file is correctly processed

Answer (score 3):

Using native Powershell utility only:

`Get-Content C:\textfile.txt | Measure-Object -Property length -Maximum`

To get the actual *content* of the longest line:

`Get-Content C:\textfile.txt | Sort-Object -Property length | Select-Object -last 1`

Comment: Best method. Easy, reliable, system tools only, no batch required

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a maxlength=0
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q27898945.txt) DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 CALL :calc
)

ECHO maxlength IN file is %maxlength%

GOTO :EOF

:calc
SET "line2=!line:~%maxlength%!"
IF DEFINED line2 set/a maxlength+=1&GOTO calc
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q27898945.txt` containing some random text for testing.

Will show some sensitivity to content - lines containing `%text%` for instance will be miscalculated.

Answer (score 0):

Using my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
jrepl "$" "if ($off>max) max=$off;false" /f test.txt /jbeg "var max=0" /jend "output.WriteLine(max)" /jmatch
```

Prefix JREPL with CALL if you want to use it in a script.

If you want to capture the value in a variable within a batch script:

```
for %%N in (
  'call jrepl "$" "if ($off>max) max=$off;false" /f test.txt /jbeg "var max=0" /jend "output.WriteLine(max)" /jmatch'
) do set /a max=%%N
```